# Problems with const members of a union within a structure

Tags: c++

I wanted to declare some parts of the structure as being const as I'm passing it to a 3rd party in an API call.  I'm planning to populate the values by casting away const using a C style cast.  That allows me to set them but the user of the API knows that these are input values as they can't easily set them.

Cutting it down to a simple example, I have

```
struct mystruct
{
  union valuesUnion
  {
    const int32_t integer;
    const double real;
    valuesUnion() : integer(0), real(0.0) {}
  } values;
  mystruct() : values(valuesUnion())
  {
  }
};

int main()
{
  mystruct a;
}
```

Note that I had to add a constructor for "mystruct" or you get a compilation error due to uninistalised const variables.

But I get an error -

g++     Z.cpp   -o Z
Z.cpp: In constructor âmystruct::valuesUnion::valuesUnion()â:
Z.cpp:11:5: error: initializations for multiple members of âmystruct::valuesUnionâ
make: *** [Z] Error 1

I can fix this if I change the union constructor to read -

```
valuesUnion() : integer(0) {}
```

I then don't get an error from g++ but it fails to compile on Visual Studio 2012 -

valuesUnion::real' : must be initialized in constructor base/member initializer list

Am I going about this the wrong way?

Thanks.

Comment: Any reason not to make the `union` itself `const`?

Comment: "I'm planning to populate the values by casting away const using a C style cast." - giving undefined behaviour. I wouldn't do that.

Comment: Why would you ever want a constant to have two different types, stored in the same memory area? It does smell like muddy program design.

Comment: Mike - I've realised C style cast doesn't work with GNU compiler so now using const_cast - now I figured out how to use it!  Lundin - they are not really constants.  I'm setting the value, then passing the entire structure to another library developer.  They can set some of the items in the struct value that I'll read back but I don't want them setting things that should only be read only to them.

Comment: Chowlett - I think that may solve the issue.  Hadn't thought of that.

Comment: Since this is ostensibly C++, you shouldn't be doing any of what you're doing. Those are implementation details. The item setting should be done by inline accessor methods. That's what encapsulation is for, and that's why you're using C++, not C. If you intended this to be a C question, then please tag appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

Union isn't like class or struct as the two "attributes" reference the same memory unit.
You can only initialize this memory once you are giving two initializations for the same memory area.

If you change

```
union valuesUnion
```

for

```
struct valuesUnion
```

Then you can check that your initialization list is right for different memory areas.

Comment: @PeterS In that case you should use just one initializer. integer(0) will set all the union bits to 0 then you will get 0.0 when consulting the union as a double. There is no need for double(0.0) initializer.

Comment: Ah - but check my question again.  At the end I explain that compiling on VS 2012 will generate another error if you don't initialize all of them!  I have the answer now - mark the union as const.  It was given to me as a comment so I can't mark it as answered.